# Toggle vue-multiselect close/open on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, vue-multiselect

When I click on the button, multiselect opens.
But when I click on the button a second time, the true / false values ​​flash and as a result, isOpen remains true.
What am I doing wrong?

template:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggle">open and close later
  </button>
    <pre>{{ isOpen }}</pre>
  <multiselect 
    ref="multiselect"
    v-model="value" 
    :options="options"
    :multiple="true"
    track-by="library"
    :custom-label="customLabel"
    @close="isOpen = false"
    @open="isOpen = true"
    >
  </multiselect>
</div>
```

js:

```
new Vue({
    components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
    },
    data: {
    isOpen: false,
    value: { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue-Multiselect' },
    options: [
        {   language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue.js' },
      { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue-Multiselect' },
      { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vuelidate' }
    ]
    },
  methods: {
    toggle () {
        if (this.isOpen) {
        this.$refs.multiselect.$el.blur();
        this.isOpen = false;
      }
      else {
        this.$refs.multiselect.$el.focus();
        this.isOpen = true;
      }

    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/46s5aknt/

Comment: It's possible by accessing $ref.deactivate(), [see my previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66151434/close-form-multi-select-on-button-click-vuejs/70448588)

Comment: It's possible by accessing $ref.deactivate(), [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66151434/close-form-multi-select-on-button-click-vuejs/70448588)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I dug the source code of this component, unfortunately, I realized there is not any "legit" way to make works your requirement. @blur callback will be called no matter what. There is no way to regulate this behavior.

Workaround: some aspect of locking with a cooldown time...

```
new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },
  data: {
  blocked: false,
  value: { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue-Multiselect' },
  options: [
    { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue.js' },
    { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue-Multiselect' },
    { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vuelidate' }
  ]
},
  methods: {
    toggle () {
      if (!this.blocked) {
        this.$refs.multiselect.toggle();
      }
    },
    block () {
      this.blocked = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.blocked = false;
      }, 200);
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `VueMultiselect` closes when there is a click outside the component.

So when you press the click button (on your mouse) `VueMultiselect` closes and when you release the click button you are actually reopening `VueMultiselect` since `isOpen` was set to false in the `close` event.

So your button can only be an Open button.

Edit:

The best solution would be to hide the button when the `VueMultiselect` is open.

Comment: Thanks. 
How can I change an example to get the right behavior?

Comment: I would hide the open button when the select is opened `<button v-if="!isOpen" @click="toggle">`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post but I just thought I'd add what I just figured out.  (SIDE NOTE : This is most likely the incorrect way to do this...  But it works)

I wanted to "close" the dropdown but I didn't want to have to click away to close the dropdown.

When going through the node modules for "vue-multi-select". I saw that with the use of refs you can actually call the "closeMultiSelect()" function to close the dropdown.

Below is an example of me wrapping the component in a div to apply the event listener to the whole component.

```
<div v-on:mouseleave="close()">
<vue-multi-select
    :ref="'multiselect'"
    v-model="selectedGroups"
    :selectOptions="options"
    :options="{multi : true}"
    :btnLabel="() => `Contact Groups`"
    :key="multiSelectComponentKey"
    search
></vue-multi-select>
</div>
```

Here is how I invoked the method to close the dropdown:

```
method:{
    close: function(){
        this.refs.multiselect.closeMultiSelect();  // this will close the dropdown
    }
}
```

The same concept can be used to open the dropdown:

```
method:{
    open: function(){
        this.refs.multiselect.openMultiSelect();  // this will open the dropdown
    }
}
```

And that's all...  If this helped anyone awesome! If you know of a better way please let me know so we can update this with the correct way.